# ccall import of emscripten export in GHCJS

Tags: javascript, c, haskell, emscripten, ghcjs

I'm trying to port the haskell library [minisat](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/minisat) to JavaScript using ghcjs, for integration in a larger haskell-ghcjs project.

minisat contains a couple of ffi imports from a c library. I've manged to compile the c library to javascript using emscripten, and to export the functions that minisat requires. So far, so good.

However, there are a couple of imports that look like this:

`foreign import ccall safe minisat_solve :: Solver -> Int -> Ptr (Lit) -> IO (Bool)`

which imports a function that looks like this:

`int  minisat_solve(minisat_solver *s, int len, minisat_Lit *ps)`

My understanding, from [the documentation](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#calling-compiled-c-functions-from-javascript-using-ccall-cwrap), is that when emscripten exports a function that takes or returns a pointer, the pointer becomes a JavaScript number type.

The [ghcjs documentation](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs/blob/master/doc/foreign-function-interface.md) suggests that it should be possible to leave the existing foreign imports in place, by appropriately wrapping a JavaScript function. However, ghcjs represents pointer types as roughly a pair consisting of a JavaScript object and number.

I think the wrapper code should be roughly

```
function h$minisat_solve(...){
   ...
   minisat_solve(...)
   ...
}

function minisat_solve = Module.cwrap('minisat_solve',...,...)
```

But I'm stumped by the type mismatch.

So, here's the challenge: Explain how to properly wrap an emscripten export for `ccall` import by `ghcjs`, using the above wrapper code as an example (or a counterexample, if I've got it completely wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Pointer types can be converted to and from integers: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Foreign-Ptr.html#t:IntPtr . Thus, you ought to be able to convert to / from any format that emscripten requires using those functions.